# How to check a string is escaped twice or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is is possible to find a string is escaped twice or not using SQL Query (REGEXP) or using PHP?
Please help me on this. I tried more to find it but I'm not getting it anywhere.

```
$item = "Zak's Laptop";
$escaped_item = mysql_escape_string($item);
$escaped_item_twice = mysql_escape_string($escaped_item);
```

Here i need to find out that `$escaped_item_twice` is escaped twice. by their result string which is stored in db already. (i.e) i already stored some strings in db with double escape. I want to get those things and to use `stripslashes()` on that data. How can i get that data?

Comment: You cannot. Please tell us what the real problem is and we might be able to help.

Comment: My problem is, i already stored some datas in db by doing double escape. I want to get those datas and to use stripslashes() on those datas and store it again. How can i get those datas which are escaped twice and stored?

Comment: So your question is "How do I select data from database"?

Comment: how could you possibly know that the sequence `\'` was not deliberately inputed, and is therefore not an escaped sequence? (If the answer you find is `you can't` then there is a good chance you cannot detect double escaping.) Also, I agree with @kapa: you are probably taking the problem the wrong way around.

Comment: Possible but insecure.

Comment: insecure in the mean?

Comment: You should just avoid using `mysql_escape_string` altogether because [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) functions are [deprecated and should no longer be used](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/update-deprecated-mysql-extension-pdo_mysql/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a difference. Escaping is nothing more than adding some `\`s (in this case). It leaves no other trail. You cannot tell whether double escaping occurred or you simply wanted to escape an escape character (`\\`) that was meant to be there.

Comment: So, no solution is there for this?

Comment: @VinothBabu Nothing reliable. You have to find the double-escaped data by some different means. How much data is it?

Comment: for that also i want the solution to find. :) but around 1500

Comment: You have to find the double-escaped data by some different means. May i know how?

Comment: @VinothBabu Do you save timestamps with your data (you should)? You could find the ones that were saved in the timeframe you had the bad code in effect. Other way I could think of is collecting data that is "suspected" or look like being double-escaped, then verifying yourself (could take some time and is error-prone).

Comment: I do save timestamps. But, may i know what error will occur if we try to solve using code without manually?

Comment: @VinothBabu You may unescape stuff you did not want to, possibly breaking your original data.

Comment: if i go like this? strpos($data, "\\\'");

Comment: @VinothBabu If you have further questions, please ask another question.

Comment: i itself created one script for this problem: :)